# How to write to two different csv files concurrently in Go?

Tags: csv, go, concurrency, goroutine

I've created a minimal reproduceable example

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "sync/atomic"
    "time"
)

var (
    csvOnePath = "test.csv"
    csvTwoPath = "test_two.csv"
)

type A struct {
    Running     int32 // used atomically
    QuitChan    chan struct{}
}

func NewA() *A {
    return &A{
        QuitChan: make(chan struct{}),
    }
}

func (a *A) Start() error {
    if ok := atomic.CompareAndSwapInt32(&a.Running, 0, 1); !ok {
        return fmt.Errorf("Cannot start service A: service already started")
    }
    go a.record()
    return nil
}

func (a *A) Stop() error {
    if ok := atomic.CompareAndSwapInt32(&a.Running, 1, 0); !ok {
        return fmt.Errorf("Cannot stop service A: service already stopped")
    }
    close(a.QuitChan)
    return nil
}

func (a *A) record() {
    //file_one, err := os.OpenFile(csvOnePath, os.O_APPEND|os.O_CREATE|os.O_WRONLY, 0755)
    file_one, err := os.Create(csvOnePath)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    writer := csv.NewWriter(file_one)
    // writer, closeFileFunc, err := NewCsvWriter(csvOnePath)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    header := []string{"this", "is", "a", "test"}
    err = writer.Write(header)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    ticker := time.NewTicker(10*time.Second)
    for {
        select {
        case t := <-ticker.C:
            err = writer.Write([]string{fmt.Sprintf("%2d:%2d:%2d", t.Hour(), t.Minute(), t.Second())})
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
                a.QuitChan <- struct{}{}
            }
        case <-a.QuitChan:
            ticker.Stop()
            writer.Flush()
            file_one.Close()
            fmt.Println("Stopped recording.")
            break
        }
    }
}

type B struct {
    Running     int32 // used atomically
    QuitChan    chan struct{}
}

func NewB() *B {
    return &B{
        QuitChan: make(chan struct{}),
    }
}

func (b *B) Start() error {
    if ok := atomic.CompareAndSwapInt32(&b.Running, 0, 1); !ok {
        return fmt.Errorf("Cannot start service B: service already started")
    }
    go b.record()
    return nil
}

func (b *B) Stop() error {
    if ok := atomic.CompareAndSwapInt32(&b.Running, 1, 0); !ok {
        return fmt.Errorf("Cannot stop service B: service already stopped")
    }
    close(b.QuitChan)
    return nil
}

func writeMsgToReport(report *csv.Writer, msg string) error {
    ct := time.Now()
    timestamp := fmt.Sprintf("%2d:%2d:%2d", ct.Hour(), ct.Minute(), ct.Second())
    return report.Write([]string{timestamp, msg})
}

func (b *B) record() {
    //file_two, err := os.OpenFile(csvTwoPath, os.O_APPEND|os.O_CREATE|os.O_WRONLY, 0666)
    file_two, err := os.Create(csvTwoPath)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    writer := csv.NewWriter(file_two)
    //writer, closeFileFunc, err := NewCsvWriter(csvTwoPath)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    header := []string{"this", "is", "a", "second", "test"}
    err = writer.Write(header)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    ticker := time.NewTicker(1*time.Second)
    ticks := 0
    for {
        select {
        case <-ticker.C:
            if ticks % 15 == 0 {
                err = writeMsgToReport(writer, "YEET "+strconv.Itoa(ticks))
                if err != nil {
                    fmt.Println(err)
                    b.QuitChan <- struct{}{}
                }
            }
            ticks++
        case <-b.QuitChan:
            ticker.Stop()
            writer.Flush()
            file_two.Close()
            fmt.Println("Stopped recording.")
            break
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    serviceA := NewA()
    err := serviceA.Start()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    defer serviceA.Stop()
    serviceB := NewB()
    err = serviceB.Start()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    defer serviceB.Stop()
    time.Sleep(600*time.Second)
}
```

Essentially, I have two different services that run a `record` method in two different goroutines. They each create and write to a different csv file at different times. When I run this, the csv files are created but never have data. No errors are ever raised while running this. I read that I should use a mutex which I've implemented but this hasn't worked either. What should I do here?

Comment: I briefly skimmed the code and noticed that `closeFileFunc()` is called before `writer.Flush()`.   Should the order be swapped?  It does not look like the mutex in CsvWriter is needed because there's no concurrent access to a given CsvWriter.  If this is correct, then simplify the code by using the enconding/csv package directly from the record methods.

Comment: I'll reverse the order of the close and flush, remove the mutex and report back. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure the channel method is the best here, though it is possible. You could use [WaitGroup](https://pkg.go.dev/sync#WaitGroup) to accomplish what you want, by adding 2 and simply blocking until they're done.

Comment: I would need the channel method to work. In the actual project this is from, I'm writing data in real time from two different sources to two different files at different intervals.

Comment: Is the data you're writing the same in both files?  If so you could use io.MultiWriter

Comment: Unfortunately no. One is getting data from an OPC DA server, the other is writing strings into the csv to be used for a report later on.

Comment: As per [the spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Program_execution) your program exits when `main()` completes "It does not wait for other (non-main) goroutines to complete." ([example](https://play.golang.org/p/wjFrV2l8xZw)). This means your `goroutines` are *probably* being killed before flushing/closing the file. There are a few ways to fix this; a `WaitGroup` being the obvious one.

Comment: @Brits you're right! That fixed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As detailed in the comments the program will exit when `main()` completes; [the spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Program_execution) states "It does not wait for other (non-main) goroutines to complete.".

This means that it is unlikely that your go routines will process the code that closes the files meaning that buffered data may not be written.

I created a simplified version of your application in [the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/wjFrV2l8xZw) to demonstrate this.

There are a number of ways to fix this but the simplest is probably to add a `WaitGroup` so your application can wait for the go routines to exit before terminating.